# Calculate average in scala

Tags: scala

I'm getting a session from database which content result which content dimensions, now I'm trying to calculate average for dimensions:

```
sessionService.findById(sessionId).map {
  case Some(session) =>
    val result = session.result.getOrElse(Seq.empty)
    for (dimension <- result.dimensions) {
      var test += dimension.average
    }

    Ok(Json.toJson(session)).as("application/json")
  case None => NotFound(Json.toJson("Not found"))

}
```

but I get this error : [image]

UPDATE :

When trying

```
var test = 0
for (dimension <- result.dimensions) {
  test += dimension.average
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
var test += dimension.average
```

is invalid syntax. You can't simultaneously declare and increase a variable... well it just doesn't make sense.

You probably meant something like

```
var test = 0
for (dimension <- result.dimensions) {
  test += dimension.average
}
```

---

By the way, have you considered a different, more functional approach?

```
val test = result.dimensions.reduce(_ + _.average)
```

---

About the update, the problem is with `getOrElse(Seq.empty)`

You can try something like

```
sessionService.findById(sessionId).map {

  case Some(Session(_, _, Some(result), _)) =>
    result.dimensions.reduce { case (avg, d) => avg + d.average }

  case None =>
    NotFound(Json.toJson("Not found"))

}
```

Comment: well, that's a problem with your data. What should dimension be?

Comment: @Rajeun sorry but this question is becoming too broad, and I'm basically debugging your code for you. Please open a more specific question